# How do I return two variables in one Django HttpResponse?

Tags: python, json, django, http

Ok, I'm pretty new to django and I was building a very simple app. User enters location into a textbox, I fetch the co-ordinates for that location from google maps and print it in the next page. So far, I have been able to get the co-ordinates in a JSON file along with a lot of other information. I have also successfully isolated the latitudes and longitudes and stored them into separate variables. I can't get them to print though. Only one value gets printed. Could someone help me with this? This is what I've written so far:
My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
import requests
import json
# Create your views here.


def homepage(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'geog/homepage.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        string = request.POST['location']
        maps_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+string
        json_string = requests.get(maps_url).content
        json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
        lat = json_dict['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
        lng = json_dict['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
        return HttpResponse(lat, lng) #It only prints lat, does not print lng
```

My Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>geog</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name='location'/>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create one string with both values and put in `HttpResponse()` or use `render()` with another html file and `lat, lng` as arguments (and with `{{ lat }}`, `{{ lng }}` in html)

Comment: If I have to use render, I have to create a new template and new urls. String idea sounds better.

Answer (score 1):

it would be

```
# this will return a json object with a lat and lng property which have the desired values
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"lat":lat, "lng":lng}), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: In this case you better use django.http.JsonResponse - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#id4